# FMU Creation in OpenModelica

Tags: openmodelica

I have created BouncingBall FMU using OpenModelica-V1.12. I am able to Launch the FMU using Python (OMSimulator-V2.0). It works fine.

---

When I create the FMU using OpenModelica-V1.13 and above, unable to load the FMU in Python. Application crashes and it shows the error '**This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information'**

---

Size of the FMU created using OpenModelica-V1.12: 16.2 MB,

Size of the FMU created using OpenModelica-V1.12 : 1.27 MB

Comment: Can you try with the nightly builds?
https://build.openmodelica.org/omc/builds/windows/nightly-builds/
There was a bug that should be fixed in master and the upcoming 1.13.2:
https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/5293

Comment: Hi Adiran, Thanks for your reply. I have already tested with the nightly builds (OpenModelica-v1.14.0-dev-79-g8167b9d2b-64bit.exe) and issue remains same.

Comment: In OMEdit, change Tools->Options->FMI->Platforms to static and see if it works like that.

Comment: Hi, I tested by setting the FMI Platforms to static. Still unable to load the FMU in Python

Comment: Seems there is another issue. Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: Hi Adrian, I tested with today's version (OpenModelica-v1.14.0-dev-91-gbbc721e3b-64bit.exe). Still unable to load the FMU in python. The FMU file is less in size. Thank You

Comment: Hi Adrian, I have tested the issue with the latest version (OpenModelica-1.13.2). I am able to create the FMU and able to launch FMU using Python. Thank You